# How do I hide a GtkSpinButton in XML

Tags: xml, ubuntu, gtk

I'm trying to hide a GtkSpinButton on the Time and Date UI on Ubuntu so the user can only edit Timezone, but no success at all! I can set the visibility property of labels and stuff and it works just fine. But when I edit the visibility for the dynamic spin button where the user can edit hours, minutes and seconds, setting False just doesn't work. Any ideas? The file I'm editing, on Ubuntu 10.04, is at /usr/share/gnome-system-tools/ui/time.ui

Answer (score 2):

you are not meant to change the XML file of a project installed on disk: the UI description files are part of the application logic, not configuration files.

the UI description is used to generate UI elements; the application will then manipulate those elements internally, so you cannot just set the "visible" property value to FALSE and hope for the best.

what you want to achieve can only be done by patching the application not to show the time UI, recompile it, and repackage everything.